# Questions about the Photovoltaic Effect

Tags: electricity, electrons, electric-fields, solar-cells

So this is my second query about the photovoltaic effect. I've looked into it more and understood it for the most part, but there's still something I don't completely get. After the electrons are excited into the conduction band, some sources say that they can't cross into the opposite material due to an electric field blocking their path and would need an external circuit, others say that some electrons do cross into the other material but their flow gets halted gradually into nothing by the formation of a depletion region, and would then need an external circuit to maintain a consistent flow.

So which one is it? Another question is, what exactly causes the electrons to move in the first place? Their attraction to the holes in the opposite material? Simple as that?

Much obliged, and thank you for your time.

Bonus: If you could explain in a general context, rather than in relation to P-N junctions, you get extra brownie points.

Comment: A depletion region is intrinsically tied to the electrical field.  Is there a reason you wish the explanations to be separated from one another?

Comment: So do the electrons not cross at all without  an external circuit or simply trickle in until their flow is stopped and would need one eventually? As for the separation, that's because the photovoltaic effect isn't exclusive to p-n junctions, and so I'd like to understand it on a general level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the basis of the photovoltaic effect is the idea that a photon can excite an electron, causing it to jump from the valance band to the conduction band.  This occurs in all materials, not just p-n junctions.  Typically the electron and the "hole" created in the valance band remain relatively close together, and eventually the electron drops back down.  However, it is possible to construct scenarios where the electron and the hole prefer to take different paths.  The first observation of this came from  A. E. Becquerel in 1839 using precious metal sheets in an acid or base, and lighting one of them.  The effect there was similar to a wet-cell battery, in that the "hole" got captured chemically and transported through the liquid while the electron went through a conductor (and was measured).

The [p-n junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_solar_cells#/media/File:Solargif1.gif) is an easy way to cause them to take different paths.  In the case of a p-n junction, the borrowing of electrons across the junction creates a "depletion zone," building up an increasingly strong electric field until it achieves an equilibrium.  Now, if a photon excites an electron, there is a statistical probability that it will enter a region near the junction where the electrical field creates a noticeable electrical potential.  The electron crosses the gap and then gets isolated from the hole because of the energy potential.  Now there's an electron on one side and a hole on the other, generating a voltage.

What I just described sounds a lot like the "electric field blocking their path" story.  However, it's worth noting that the depletion zone viewpoint is also valid.  Assuming you don't short-circuit your photocell, you're going to accumulate electrons on one side of the p-n junction.  This is going to cause the balance in the depletion zone to shift.  Some of those electrons and holes that were displaced by the photons will be added to the depletion zone until the electric field across it is sufficient to equalize the flow once again.  This is actually nothing special at all -- it's simply the normal operation of a p-n junction diode as the voltage across it increases.

Once the depletion zone is built up enough for the particular voltage possible for the material, then you no longer see electrons or holes enlarging the depletion zone.  After that point, the original explanation (using only electric fields) applies.

Comment: Thank you so much. So in the end, the use of an external circuit arises from the need for curbing the development of a depletion region to maintain the flow of electrons, correct?

Comment: I think you're approaching photovoltaics from an interesting perspective, based on that wording.  Most people would not say they "use" an external circuit to maintain some properties in the PV cell, they would say the entire point of the PV cell is to be used, and the internal properties do what is needed =)

Comment: Well it just makes more sense to me that the tech is implemented to manipulate a natural process to reach our desired efficiency =)

Comment: Without an external circuit, the photovoltaic cell will reach its own equilibrium depletion region, based on the physical properties of the cell (I believe the most important is the band-gap between the valence band and the conduction band).

Answer (score 1):

The photovoltaic effect in a pn-junction is most easily explained by knowing the essentials of a pn-junction. Already without applying a voltage  to a pn-junction, in thermodynamic equilibrium, there exists a so-called built-in positive electrostatic potential difference $V_{bi}$ between the n-type and the p-type semiconductor region. This built-in potential difference and associated electric field is generated by the space charge located in the carrier depletion zone between the p- and n-regions. It prevents further charge carrier flow due to the originally different chemical potentials of the p- and n-doped semiconductors upon reaching equilibrium after the junction formation.

When illuminating an open circuited pn-junction, electron and holes generated in the semiconductor in or near the depletion zone reaching it by diffusion, will be transported by the built-in electric field to the n-side and to the p-side of the junction, respectively. This means that the built-in voltage is reduced by a voltage $V_{oc}$ which is the measurable open circuit photo-voltage of the pn-junction, a positive voltage of the p-side with respect to the n-side. When you connect a load resistance to the junction terminals, a current will flow out of the p-terminal and into the n-terminal which generates power in the load.